# Did yodlee updated the API recently?

Tags: yodlee

Did yodlee updated the API recently?  we have a yodlee program in production, which works well for more than one year. But since last week, the program started to sending back the wrong transactions.

Before, when getting transactions back using yodlee, we passed in start and end date to filter them and we can get correct results back. But since last week, the same program started to send back the transactions of different date range. For example, we need the transactions of the day before yesterday, and program works well for more than one year, but since last week, it started to send back the transactions of two days before yesterday.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

As per recent release there were no changes done related to Transaction Search Service. You are a customer of Yodlee Interactive services, I'd suggest you to raise a Service Request to Yodlee Customer Care team and explain your problem with some sample itemIds and they'll followup with you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. How could i raise a service request? Is there any webpage for this?

Comment: You should be having access to Yodlee Customer Care tool, you should have received the details about it during your agreement. Please refer to that.